# Implementing a simple local memory cache on an Azure instance

Tags: c#, .net, caching, azure, azure-caching

I'm looking for a simple way to implement a **local memory store** which can be used on an Azure .NET instance

I've been looking at [Azure Co-located Caching](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) and it seems to support all of my requirements:

1. Work on both web roles and worker roles
2. Implement a simple LRU
3. Keep cached objects in memory (RAM)
4. Allow me to define the cache size as a percentage of the machine's total RAM
5. Keep the cache on the same machine of the web/worker role (co-located mode)
6. Allow me to access the same cache from multiple AppDomains running on the same machine (Web Roles may split my handlers into different AppDomains)

The only problem I have with Azure Co-located caching is that different instances communicate and try to share their caches - and I don't really need all that.

I want every machine to have its own separate in-memory cache. When I query this cache, I don't want to waste **any** time on making a network request to other instances' caches.

**Local Cache config?**

I've seen a configuration setting in Azure Caching to enable a [Local Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914126.aspx) - but it still seems like machines may communicate with each other (ie. during cache miss). This config also requires a `ttlValue` and `objectCount` and I want TTL to be "forever" and the object count to be "until you fill the entire cache". It feels like specifying `maxInt` in both cases seems wrong.

**What about a simple static variable?**

When I really think about it, all this Azure caching seems like a bit of an overkill for what I need. I basically just need a static variable in the application/role level.. except that doesn't work for requirement #6 (different AppDomains). Requirement #4 is also a bit harder to implement in this case.

**Memcached**

I think good old `memcached` seems to do exactly what I want. Problem is I'm using Azure as a PaaS and I don't really want to administer my own VM's. I don't think I can install `memcached` on my roles.. [UPDATE] It seems it is possible to run memcached locally on my roles. Is there a more elegant "native" solution without using memcached itself?

Comment: What kind of things are you caching? Keep in mind that only strings and a few special objects (threads, appdomains) are really shared across appdomains, all other stuff is serialized and deserialized when crossing appdomain boundaries. Then there is MarshalByRefObject — which is not exactly shared, but calls from different appdomains are marshaled to its native appdomain. You can create a MarshalByRef dictionary, put it in a static and use it across appdomains.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy I want to cache simple JSON objects (a flat dictionary of about 8 strings, each one being about 100-200 bytes). Can you point me somewhere with an example implementation of your idea, it sounds perfect

Comment: I couldn't find any. However do you really need this? The role entry point runs in a different process than the web role [(1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx), but if your web role has just one site it runs in one appdomain. Just put your static cache in Global.asax and you should be all set.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy My web role has several handlers (ashx files) and I'm not sure whether they run on different AppDomains or not. I prefer not to risk it and make assumptions

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly install memcached on Web and Worker roles.  Steve Marx blogged [getting memcached running on Azure Cloud Service](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/memcached-in-windows-azure) several years ago before the Virtual Machine features were present.  This is an older post, so you may run into other ways of dealing with this, such as using [start up tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) instead of the OnStart method in RoleEntryPoint, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware memcached was possible. Are you aware of a more "native" solution besides memcached for this purpose?

Comment: Nothing out of the box. The co-located Windows Azure Caching feature you mentioned already is the closest. You could write your own service that starts up locally and is a memory cache using the .NET Framework caching namespace that could be accessed cross app domain, but that seems overkill if you could use a cache framework that was already created.  I didn't ask why you didn't really want a distributed cache because I assume you have your reasons. I'd at least test the latency if that is what you are concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the "free" versions of SQL Server for local caching and they have worked great.  It depends on what you are doing, but I have ran both SQL Server Express/Compact for storing entire small static data sets for a fantasy football site I wrote that included 5 years of statistics.  They worked really well even on a small/medium Azure instances, because of the small footprint.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx

Best part is you can use t-sql.  Your cache requirements might be more complex or not scale to this.